# Refind Boot Too Slow 30 Seconds

Tags: boot, macintosh, refind

I have installed refind on it's own dedicated partition on my Macbook Pro so that I can boot Linux, but it takes almost 30 seconds between switching the computer on and seeing the refind menu. Is there any way to speed up the boot process using refind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150670/install-refind-on-os-x-10-10-yosemite) solves this problem. Specifically:

> 1. By security, I added all the "drivers_x64" folder by doing `./install.sh --alldrivers` at the rEFInd installation
> 2. On my EFI partition under Yosemite (stored on`/dev/disk0s1`), I renamed the "refind" folder to "BOOT"
> 3. Inside that folder, I renamed "refind_x64.efi" to "bootx64.efi"